# Index/Match formula brings up file open dialog when other formulas do not

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

### Context

I have a weird oddity with my spreadsheet. It's a report that pulls data from other spreadsheets, one workbook for each quarter. This pull is done using an index/match formula that looks at the given quarter's table. All workbooks are in the same directory on the network and when I initially set the index/match a dialog box popped up asking me to select the desire file.

The formula is

```
=INDEX('Directory-to-File[3rd Quarter Workbook.xlsx]Sheet1'!$H:$H,MATCH(J:J,'Directory-to-File[3rd Quarter Workbook.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B:$B,0))
```

### The problem

One of the quarters' formula doesn't update when the quarter's workbook is updated. Furthermore, whenever you try to edit the cell (or drag/drop the formula down the column) the dialog box pops up asking me to select the workbook again. The other quarters do not have this problem.

Any ideas what leads to this difference?

Comment: You did not include the formula you are talking about in your post.

Comment: I didn't think it super necessary as it's just a typical index match. Though in the process of adding it to my question I discovered a typo. Answer coming shortly

Comment: 'the dialog box pops up asking me to select the workbook again' sounds like the file you're pointing the formula to doesn't exist

Comment: @AlexM, normally yes, but the file is there. If I select the file through the dialog, then click in the cell to edit (but not change anything) the box pops up again. There was a typo in the filename and despite selecting the file through the dialog, excel wasn't changing the formula to the proper filename.

Comment: So in other words... the file the formula was pointing to didn't exist? It is an interesting note that re-selecting the file thru the dialog leaves the formula untouched. Good find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the file open dialog pops up, it's Excel asking the user to clarify the desired spreadsheet. However, if the dialog keeps popping up, then Excel cannot find the file as it is listed in the formula. Selecting the file via the dialog is a short term fix to get the index/match formula to work, but does not actually change the formula itself. IE, if there is a typo, the dialog box allows the user to select the file without the typo, but does not fix the formula so the issue will continue to rise.

Double check that the directory is correct and that the filename is spelled correctly. In this case, a letter e was omitted in the filename. Fixing the typo results in the dialog not popping up after editing the formula.